# php using if and else if statement

Tags: php, select

I am trying to create this page that gives different comments when different values of mass (of cats :3) are submitted by using if and else if. However the comment does not show up when I hit submit and I could not figure out the problem.

This is my code:

```
<?
if ($_POST['subBtn']) { 
$mass = $_POST['theMass'];
$colour = $_POST['theColour'];
$name = $_POST['theName'];
$comment = $_POST['theComment'];
echo "<p> The name of the cat is <b>" . $name . "</b>, the colour is  <b>" . $colour . "</b>, the mass is <b>" . $mass . "." . $comment . "</p>";}
?>

<?
if ($_POST['subBtn']) {
$mass = $_POST['theMass'];

if ($mass <= 0 AND NULL ) {
$comment = "INVALID";

} else if ($mass >= 0 AND $mass <=2.5) {
$comment = "Skin and bones!!!";

} else if ($mass > 2.5 AND $mass<=5) {
$comment = "Small but healthy";

} else if ($mass > 5 AND $mass<=10) {
$comment = "Getting a little heavy!";

} else if ($mass >10 AND $mass<=15) {
$comment = "You may wanna hide the food!";

} else if ($mass >15 AND $mass<=20) {
$comment = "Are you sure this is a cat?";

} else if ($mass >20) {
$comment = "Need another job too feed your cat! <p>'Comment: OMG'</p>";

} else {
$comment = "<p class='error'>Nothing specific to comment...sorry try again</p>";

}
}
?>

<p>     

<form action="crazy-cats.php" method="post">
Colour of the Cat:
<select name="theColour">
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="green">Green</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
<option value="black">Black</option>
</select>  

Mass: <input type="text" name="theMass" value="" /><br />
    <br />
Name: <input type="text" name="theName" value="" /><br />

<input type="submit"name="subBtn" value="submit"/></input>

</form>
</p>
```

Comment: your missing a `echo $comment;`

Comment: `elseif` is all one word

Comment: @OliverQueen its valid as 2 http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php not always true.

Comment: @kingkero are you? you what?

Comment: "you can also write 'else if' (in two words) and the behavior would be identical to the one of 'elseif' (in a single word). The syntactic meaning is slightly different (if you're familiar with C, this is the same behavior) **but the bottom line is that both would result in exactly the same behavior.** "

Comment: " Note: Note that elseif and else if will only be considered exactly the same when using curly brackets as in the above example. **When using a colon to define your if/elseif conditions, you must not separate else if into two words, or PHP will fail with a parse error.**"

Comment: OP is using curly brackets

Comment: This is missing a blank (space): `type="submit"name="subBtn"` ...

Comment: the troll here is the one who decides grammar is more important than helping the OP

Comment: Hi @Dagon Thanks for the comment, but if you scroll the code to the right (its a long line xD) I have a " . $comment . " , and it's part of the echo, does that not count?

Comment: @Dagon you are correct, I just don't want to give OP a faux sense of security thinking that they are the same all the time.

Comment: @OP - your echo is before the redefining of your comment, so no that doesn't count.

Comment: @sakurayui you mixing up 2 comments, see the edited answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few minor things wrong, including your PHP tags and a missing space on the submit input. You are also missing your `theComment` input. Try this

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['subBtn'])) {
    $mass = $_POST['theMass'];
    $colour = $_POST['theColour'];
    $name = $_POST['theName'];
    $comment = $_POST['theComment'];
    echo "<p> The name of the cat is <b>" . $name . "</b>, the colour is  <b>" . $colour . "</b>, the mass is <b>" . $mass . "." . $comment . "</p>";

    $mass = $_POST['theMass'];

    if ($mass <= 0 AND NULL ) {
        $comment = "INVALID";

    } else if ($mass >= 0 AND $mass <=2.5) {
        $comment = "Skin and bones!!!";

    } else if ($mass > 2.5 AND $mass<=5) {
        $comment = "Small but healthy";

    } else if ($mass > 5 AND $mass<=10) {
        $comment = "Getting a little heavy!";

    } else if ($mass >10 AND $mass<=15) {
        $comment = "You may wanna hide the food!";

    } else if ($mass >15 AND $mass<=20) {
        $comment = "Are you sure this is a cat?";

    } else if ($mass >20) {
        $comment = "Need another job too feed your cat! <p>'Comment: OMG'</p>";

    } else {
        $comment = "<p class='error'>Nothing specific to comment...sorry try again</p>";

    }
echo "my comment on mass is ". $comment;
}
?>

<p>

<form action="test.php" method="post">
    Colour of the Cat:
    <select name="theColour">
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="black">Black</option>
    </select>

    Mass: <input type="text" name="theMass" value="" /><br />
    <br />
    Name: <input type="text" name="theName" value="" /><br />

    <input type="hidden" name="theComment" value="<?= $comment ?>" />

    <input type="submit" name="subBtn" value="submit"/></input>

</form>
</p>
```

Granted, you should really consider validating your POST variables.

Comment: what about the missing mass `$comment` ?

Comment: I added the comment input at the bottom; it's there.

Comment: your mixing up the user comment and the OP's comment

Comment: @Dagon Ah, yeah. Must glanced over that. I'll fix that up.

Comment: Those are valid `PHP` tags. <? is the same as <?php

Comment: @Dagon then reverse it. Apparently I'm missing something.

Comment: no its fine, horse put together by a committee and all, :-)

Comment: Thank you sososososososoooo much @DavidWyly  #Lifesaver <3 this is super helpful thanks to everyone QAQ

Answer (score -1):

1. Check the $_POST with isset.
2. Delete $_POST['theComment'] line.
3. Put your first PHP code below the second one.
   Worked for me!

Comment: dont post comments as answers please

Comment: Sorry, I can't post comments yet. By the way is there something wrong with the answer? I just tried it and it works.

Comment: 1. he does it, 2. why? 3. no way this worked as it stands

Comment: Yeah m9, if you're gonna post something like this, make sure it includes code.

Comment: Dagon, about the 2nd one. $_POST['theComment'] does not exist in the form, so how can it be in $_POST? And the 3rd one. It is trying to echo $comment before it has an assigned value (from if statements), that's way the code in first tags should be executed after if statements.